# Tensorflow AttributeError:'LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession' object has no attribute 'make_callable'

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

When I want to use the tfdbg to find the NAN error,the error of the tfdbg comes:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 233, in _run
    enqueue_callable = sess.make_callable(enqueue_op)
AttributeError: 'LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession' object has no attribute 'make_callable'
```

I think the question is in the `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess);`

My tensorflow version is 1.2.1
python 2.7

and I use the tfdbg as below:

```
sess = tfdbg.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tfdbg.has_nan_or_inf)
```

without any change.

Please help me! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

In my Tensorflow version 1.11.0, the attribute `has_nan_or_inf` of tfdbg should be `tfdbg.has_inf_or_nan`. It could be used as follows:

```
sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tfdbg.has_inf_or_nan)
```